# Is there a difference between 'past' and 'last' in this context?

Tags: difference

> "Singing teacher Miri Gellert is nearly 30, has lived at home **for the past nine years** (Vs. for the last nine years) and has had her share of awkward encounters." (BBC)

Is there a difference between '**past**' and '**last**' in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference. With **for the past nine years** the reference time can be to *now* or *then*.

> I have lived here for the past nine years.
>
> I bought this car when I lived in Boston. I was a college student at the
>   time and had been in the city for the past four years.

But **for the last four years**, when unqualified, is spoken only with reference to *now*, not *then*.

> I have lived here for the last four years.
>
> I bought this car when I lived in Boston. I was a college student at the time and had been in the city for the last four years. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

But if the phrase is qualified, it means **final (four)**, and then it can be used in reference to *then*:

> He died in New York and had worked on Wall Street for the last four years *of his career*.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it seems to be no difference between the two.
Subtle differences (if any) are discussed here:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/in-the-last-3-months-vs-in-the-past-3-months